# The program is giving wrong output for leap year the value at the load variable is wrong i think Ex.1900,1700

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-operator, leap-year

*The program is giving wrong output for century year which are not leap Ex.1900,1700.The program is giving wrong output for leap year the value at the load variable is wrong i think Ex.1900,1700. *

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int year;
    bool t1=true;
    cout<<t1;
    bool t2=false;
    cin>>year;
    if(year%4==0)
    {
       int value=year%100?year%400?t1:t2:t1;
       cout<<value;
       if(value==t1)
       {
           cout<<"leap year";
       }
       else
       {
           cout<<"not a leap year";
       }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"not a leap year";
    }
}
```

Comment: `int value=year%100?year%400?t1:t2:t1;` just why?

Comment: What do you think `year%100?` does? Or what operator % does for ints at all?

Comment: Keep it simple.... Don't do stuff like `year%100?year%400?t1:t2:t1;`

Comment: Why do you have variables like `t1` and `t2`

Comment: Even disregarding the unreadability of `int value= ...` why did you decide to write "t1" and "t2" instead of "true" and "false"? (If you simplify it, you will find `year % 100 == 0 || year % 400 != 0`.)

Answer (score 2):

`year%100` becomes false when `year` is divisible by 100 (the remainder is zero) and becomes true when `year` is not divisible by 100 (the remainder is not zero).

`year%400` becomes false when `year` is divisible by 400 (the remainder is zero) and becomes true when `year` is not divisible by 400 (the remainder is not zero).

Therefore, you have to judge the number as not leap year when `year%100` is false and `year%400` is true, and as not leap year otherwise.

In conclusion, the line

```
int value=year%100?year%400?t1:t2:t1;
```

should be

```
bool value=year%100?t1:year%400?t2:t1;
```

Also I don't think using `int` here to assign `bool` variables is reasonable.

Comment: Sure, that's a fix, but it's still an unreadible difficult to maintain mess...

Comment: @JHBonarius: It's readable in C++ in my opinion, although the `t1` and `t2` stuff needs reworking. But bear in mind that PHP have reversed the associativity. Funny guys.

Comment: @Bathsheba nah, when a future dev will look at this code, he/she/they will have to put in some effort to understand it. I would make a func `bool IsDivisibleBy(int num, int divisor) { return num % divisor == 0; }` and one `bool IsLeapYear(int year) { return (IsDivisibleBy(year, 4) && !IsDivisibleBy(year, 100)) || IsDivisibleBy(year, 400);}`. That's something I consider readable. (I'm omitting `[[nodiscard]]`, `static`, `constexpr`, and `noexcept`)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fix in MikeCAT's answer you can also significantly simplify your code to just a few lines:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int year;
    std::cin>>year;
    bool leap = (year % 4 == 0) && ( (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0) );
    if(leap)
    {
        std::cout<<"leap year";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"not a leap year";
    }
}
```

You can use `0` being equivalent to `false` to make it shorter but I think the first version is more readable:

```
    bool leap = !(year % 4) && ( (year % 100) || !(year%400) );
```

Comment: @4386427 it doesn't look much simpler to me and mine has a theoretical tiny performance benefit from short circuit evaluation stopping after the first term for 3/4 of input values, its also in the logical order most people would think about the leap year rules

Comment: Kind of true... the logic seems more simple to me but.. your correct about the short circuit

Answer (score 1):

Once C++20 has been properly implemented by compilers (which is not yet in release) you don't have to reinvent the wheel and can use [`std::chrono::year::is_leap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year/is_leap)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    year y = 1900y;
    std::cout << "year: " << static_cast<int>(y)
              << " is " << (y.is_leap()?"":"not ") << "a leap year\n";
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oE9aKzeaM)